# convergence and divergence of series with a summand

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Does $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}\frac{n!}{(2n)!}$ converge?

I tried the ratio test however confused especially with the summand before it

Comment: The Ratio Test works well.  What matters is the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$, where $a_k$ is the $k$-th term.

Comment: when you take the limit you get zero, which doesnt seem right

Comment: I think the limit of the ratio mentioned above is $1/4$.

Comment: Could you illustrate? I dont see how

Comment: I got zero as the answer

Comment: $0$ is correct. The ratio is $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{1}{2(2n+1)} \to 0$.

Comment: You are right, that is even better for convergence.

Comment: For the sake of finding the exact rate of convergence (or getting a headache), you can also use Stirling's formula to find an asymptotic equivalent of $\frac{n!}{(2n)!}$. Something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{e}{4n}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_k=\frac{k!}{(2k)!}$. For the Ratio Test, we examine 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|.\tag{1}$$
In our case, we have
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{(n+1)!(2n)!}{n!(2n+2)!}.\tag{2}$$
The above expression simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{2(2n+1)},$$
which has limit $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus the series converges. Fast.

Comment: What is amazing is the simplicity of the infinite summation !

Answer (score -1):

We do the Ratio Test on the series as follows.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(n + 1)!}{(2n + 2)!}}{\frac{n!}{(2n)!}}\right|$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(n + 1)!}{(2n + 2)!} \times \frac{(2n)!}{n!}\right|$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{n + 1}{(2n + 2)(2n + 1)}\right|$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{2(2n + 1)}\right|$$
$$= 0.$$

Since this limit is $0 < 1,$ the series must converge.